# Groupby Two Columns - Pareto of combinations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I am fairly new to python. I have searched for an answer to this question, but am afraid I do not know the correct keywords to find it if it already exists.

I have a pandas df that consists of a column of serial numbers and some parameters that they possess. Example: SN1 has parameters A and B, SN2 has parameters A and C, etc.

```
Serial        Parameter  
SN1              A
SN1              B
SN2              C
SN2              B
SN3              D
SN4              A 
SN4              B 
SN5              D
```

When I execute df.groupby([Serial, Parameter]).sum(), I produce a new table that removes the duplicates in 'Serial' and gives a clearer picture of which SN contains what combination of parameters.

```
Serial      Parameter
SN1         A 
            B
SN2         A
            C
            B
SN3         D
SN4         A 
            B
SN5         D
```

I am interested in producing a new table out of this that shows a count for all the combinations of parameters that occur in my dataframe, so that I can produce a bar graph showing which combination occurs the most to the lesast.

I imagine it would look something like this, where 'Combination #' is a new added column to index each combination of parameters. 'Combination Count' is also a added column that is the count for the frequency of that index a nd Parameter combination remains and simply shows what combination the combination is.

```
 Combination #       Combination Count  Parameter 
    1                  2                  A
                                          B
                                          C
    2                  2                  D 
    3                  1                  A
                                          C
                                          B
```

Do I have the correct approach even to be using groupby? Some tips would be helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT: For clarity of the ask.

Comment: I fail to see the relation between the combination # column, combination count column with the original Number, parameter columns.. Can you explain further what the last table (i.e., the result you are expecting) means? Where did the numbers 4 and 5 go?

Comment: @Troy, I edited the post to make it more clear. Sorry about that! I hope this is more clear.